# rails 4 - force two arguments in route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I would like to create url in 'routes.rb'.
I've got a resource 'Source', and source_controller that has 'index' method.
In order to reach 'index', I want the user to insert an url with two arguments like that:

**source/{type}/{ids}/index**

The code I wrote in routes works:

```
resources :sources, param: :types, :only => :index do
                member do
                    get ':ids/index' => 'source#index'
                end
            end
```

It works, but is there a way to do it in more elegant way? (adding the ids to the resource somehow)

Comment: are you looking for something like this: `get 'source/:types:/:ids/index' => 'source#index'`

Comment: Yes, thanks. I copied from other controller. fixed.